Why using api.setGridOption("rowData", data) insted of native useState
I was wondering why in all Ag Grid React examples when is about to update rows data they always use the ref api.setGridOption('rowData', updatedData) instead of using the native setState(updatedData)?
It is because of a potential performance issue? Am I missing something here?
const updateData = () =>{

    ...updating logic

    //they use this
    gridRef.current!.api.setGridOption('rowData', newRowData)
    
    //instead of the obvious
    setRowData(newRowData)
}


I don't think there's anything explicitly wrong with setRowData. It does look like, as of v31, they have deprecated all API calls that set grid options (e.g. setQuickFilter, setColumnTypes) in favor of centralizing them behind setGridOption and updateGridOption.
While it may only be a partial explanation for the motivation behind the updates, they do mention that they are now doing validation on grid option configuration and I'd bet that centralizing API calls in this way allows them to do that more effectively.

Validation is now run when gridOptions are updated, meaning warnings
may appear in console when changing grid options if an invalid
configuration is reached.

They also mention that we're not able to change gridOptions directly, which seems to support that the primary reason for the API deprecations is to centralize the grid options logic in one place so they can manage/validate it more effectively.

Mutating gridOptions after the grid has been created will no longer be picked up by the grid. Instead use api.setGridOption (property, newValue) to update grid  options.


i was wondering if using the react setState maybe you will "bypass" some of the inner logic of updating data rows via api.setGridOption. Main reason of my question being if you update data set directly via api you lose pairing with the rowData you put in state.
